# Display a timer in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I am attempting to display a countdown timer in a server-side Blazor app.  My code is in both F# and C#.  The code somewhat works, but the timer never stops as intended, and the timer display sporadically does not render all of the numbers. This is my first attempt at a Blazor server-side app. I am not sure if the problem is an async issue, timer issue, or rendering issue.

Here's my code:

F#

```
let private setTimer countDown timeEvent =

    let timer = new Timer(float countDown * float 1000)
    let mutable time = 0

    time <- countDown

    timer.Elapsed.Add(fun arg ->
        time <- time - 1
        if time = 0
        then 
            timer.Stop()
            timer.Dispose()
        else
            ()
        timeEvent arg
    )

    timer.AutoReset <- true
    timer.Start()

let setTimerAsync countDown timeEvent = async{
    setTimer countDown timeEvent
    do! Async.Sleep (countDown * 1000)
}

type Timer (countDown) =

    member val CountDown : int = countDown with get,set

    member this.SetTimeAsTask (timeEvent) =
        setTimerAsync countDown timeEvent |> Async.StartAsTask
```

C# / Blazor

```
@page "/CountDown"
@using System.Timers
@using ClientTImer
@using Microsoft.FSharp.Core

<h3>Count Down</h3>
<p>
    Task: @task <br />
    Status: @status
</p>
<p>
    Timer: @time
</p>

@code {
    string task = "";
    string status = "";
    int time = 5;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        // Initial task and status
        task = "First Task";
        status = "Status One";

        Action<System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs> timeEvent =
            t =>
            {
                UpdateTime().Wait();
            };

        var func = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc(timeEvent);

        await new ClientTImer.Timer(time).SetTimeAsTask(func);

        // Update task and status
        task = "Second Task";
        status = "Status Two";
        await new ClientTImer.Timer(time).SetTimeAsTask(func);

        // Update task and status
        task = "Third Task";
        status = "Status Three";

    }

    public async Task UpdateTime()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            time--;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmunn got me on the right track, but my logic was a bit off as I did not fully understand what the timer class was actually doing.  I had to account for not only the start time but the interval as well to get everything in sync, and the code now works as intended.  Here is the updated code:

F#:

```
let private setTimer countDownSec intervalSec timeEvent =

    let timer = new Timer(float intervalSec * float 1000)
    let mutable time = 0

    time <- countDownSec

    timer.Elapsed.Add(fun arg ->
        time <- time - 1
        if time <= 0
        then 
            timer.Stop()
            timer.Dispose()
        else
            ()
        timeEvent arg
    )

    timer.AutoReset <- true
    timer.Start()

let internal setTimerAsync countDownSec intervalSec timeEvent = async{
    setTimer countDownSec intervalSec timeEvent
    do! Async.Sleep (countDownSec * 1000)
}

type Timer (countDown) =

    member val CountDown : int = countDown with get,set

    member this.SetTimeAsTask (timeEvent, interval) =
        setTimerAsync countDown interval timeEvent |> Async.StartAsTask
```

C#/Blazor:

```
@page "/CountDown"
@using System.Timers
@using ClientTImer
@using Microsoft.FSharp.Core
@using System.Threading

<h3>Count Down</h3>
<p>
    Task: @task <br />
    Status: @status
</p>
<p>
    Timer: @time
</p>

@code {
    string task = "";
    string status = "";
    int startCount = 5;
    int time;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        time = startCount;

        // Initial task and status
        task = "First Task";
        status = "Status One";

        Action<System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs> timeEvent =
            t =>
            {
                UpdateTime().Wait();
            };

        var func = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc(timeEvent);

        await new ClientTImer.Timer(startCount).SetTimeAsTask(func,1);

        // Update task and status
        task = "Second Task";
        status = "Status Two";
        await new ClientTImer.Timer(startCount).SetTimeAsTask(func,1);

        // Update task and status
        task = "Third Task";
        status = "Status Three";

    }

    public async Task UpdateTime()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            time--;

            if(time <= 0)
            {
                time = startCount;
            }

            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your F# `Timer.Elapsed` event handler, your final line is `timeEvent` (with no parameters), and I see from the rest of your code that `timeEvent` is an `Action` that's been converted to an F# function. Since you have not written any parameters after `timeEvent`, what that line is doing is specifying the *value* of `timeEvent` as the return value of the event handler, i.e. your event handler is returning a function. Or it *would* return a function if event handlers returned something other than `void` (or `unit` in F# terms). Since they don't I suspect that you've got a warning on that `timeEvent` line that says something about the value of `timeEvent` being inherently ignored.

Also, your `timer.Elapsed.Add` line in F# looks wrong to me. The `Add` method on events takes a parameter of type `'T -> unit`, where `'T` is whatever type of data the event gives you: in the case of the `Elapsed` event on timers, that would be an `ElapsedEventArgs` instance. What you should be passing to `Add` is a `fun elapsedEventArgs -> ...`. And then you'd change your `timeEvent` line to actually pass it a parameter (those same `elapsedEventArgs`) so that it gets called and actually does something.

Also, whenever you're decrementing a number and comparing it to 0, I always like to do the comparison as `<=` rather than `=`, just on the off chance that I change my code later in a way that could cause the decrement to happen twice. If my comparison is `= 0` and a double decrement takes the number from 1 to -1, the `if x = 0` branch won't trigger. But if I was comparing to `<= 0`, then it will trigger even if I make a mistake elsewhere. So I'd suggest writing `if time <= 0` rather than `if time = 0`.

In other words, I think your `timer.Elapsed` event handler needs to look like this:

```
timer.Elapsed.Add(fun evtArgs ->
    time <- time - 1
    if time <= 0
    then 
        timer.Stop()
        timer.Dispose()
    else
        ()
    timeEvent evtArgs
)
```

Comment: I made the changes to my code that you suggested, and I am still getting the exact same behavior.  This is my first time dealing with both blazor and async code, thus I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something in my logic.  To be clear what I'm trying to accomplish in this sample, is to display one task at a time for the specified timer duration. Blazor should render each number in the timer countdown, and then show the next task and so on repeating the process.